# Should I put log4j.properties file into library?

Tags: java, jar

I have a library project. This project uses log4j for logging.

Should I put log4j.properties into generated jar?
If it is not a good practice, could you tell me why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should put your log4j.properties outside your jar file because it will be easier to modify it. If the application does not force a reload of the configuration (you can do that) then a simple restart will load the config (while modifying it inside a jar file means usually a rebuild). If the application does know how to reload it, then your changes will be almost instantly applied.
This is very important when you have application in production environment, and you want to change a logging setting (like the log level) in order to get more info but not to stop the application for this (or worse, rebuild it).

Comment: All this is true, and applies to application deployments as well. There are additional reasons to not put it in a *library* project - namely that you cannot usually know the context where it will be used and configuration affecting the classpath, causing possible issues.

Comment: The ability to enable debugging on a server during a failure is a lifesaver.  As much as we test, it still only guards against the issues we thought to test for.  Having the ability to get additional detail about what's happening feeds directly into better tests going forward.

Answer (score 3):

No, I would not include `log4j.properties` in your `src/main/resources` if it's just a library - people will use your library, and people will have to configure how it should log.

But there is another problem: if you put it in your jar, others will have the log4j in their classpath too. So, if they want to have a custom configuration for log4j (which they will do), the ClassLoader will pick the first file it can find.

Also, if you have a library, I would suggest to use `slf4j` instead, so your users can choose their favourite logging framework.

For testing purpouses, it's okay to include log4j in `src/test/resources`.

Comment: I don't think OP mentioned anything about using Maven. src/main/resources and src/test/resources are Maven concepts. Other than that I agree.